# Connections without Virtualhost

Tags: apache-httpd, netstat, apache-virtualhost

I saw tons of connections on port 80. But no requests from these IP addresses were logged in Apache access/error logs. I deleted all the virtual hosts, stopped Apache, and restarted it after there are no remaining connections. After restarting Apache, the same IP addresses start making connections on the port 80 immediately.

How can a client connect when there are no virtual hosts?

Answer (score 2):

Apache works fine even without setting up Virtual Hosts.  Virtual Host(s) are needed **only** if you want to set up **additional** webservers on the same machine, and these can be either:

1. Port-based Virtual Hosts (webservers running on a different port than 80)
2. IP-based Virtual Hosts (webservers running on a different IP)
3. Name-based Virtual Host (webserver running on a different hostname; in order for this to work, the appropriate DNS records need to be specified)